# Initializing an actor in Akka, Play 2.4.2

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, akka

I have a component of my application, `Processor.java` that listens to events from an outside source. I want to use actors to pass these events into a socket. I have a a class of actors that process these events:

```
public class EventProcessor extends UntypedActor {

    static ActorRef channel = Akka.system().actorOf(Props.create(EventProcessor.class));

    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        // do stuff here
    }

    public void handleMessage(String event) {
         // tell another actor to do stuff here
    }
}
```

I want to be able to instantiate actors of type `EventProcessor` in `Process.java`. Right now, I have this:

```
ActorRef act = Akka.system().actorOf(new Props(EventProcessor.class), null);
act.handleMessage(str);
```

I am getting a compilation error:

```
constructor Props in class akka.actor.Props cannot be applied to given types;
  required: akka.actor.Deploy,java.lang.Class<?>,scala.collection.immutable.Seq<java.lang.Object>
  found: java.lang.Class<models.EventProcessor>
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

What is the correct way to instantiate an actor in Akka in my case?

Answer (score 3):

Replace `new Props(YourActor.class)` with `Props.create(Actor.class)`.
 I had the same compile error and it worked for me.
see http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.1/akka/actor/Props.html

```
final Props props = Props.create(MyActor.class, arg1, arg2);
```